# How to alias prefixed CSV columns to a Map with SimpleFlatMapper?

Tags: java, csv, simpleflatmapper

### Background

Using SimpleFlatMapper sfm-csv 6.0.3

#### Example CSV:

```
|------|-------------|----------------|----------------|------------------|
| name | reference # | pf.first thing | pf.secondThing | pf.another.thing |
|======|=============|================|================|==================|
| foo  | eb2e23c0d6a | a value here   |                | another value    |
|------|-------------|----------------|----------------|------------------|
| bar  | 0a4bba4c1d0 | values         | all            | throughout       |
|------|-------------|----------------|----------------|------------------|
```

#### Pojo

```java
class Item {

    private String name;
    private String reference;
    private Map<String, String> prefixedFields;

    // ... builder, getters, etc.

}
```

#### Simplified code

```
final CsvMapper<Item> mapper = CsvMapperFactory.newInstance()
    .addAlias("name", "itemName")
    .addAlias("reference #", "reference")
    .newMapper(Item.class);

return CsvParser.mapWith(mapper)
    .stream(file, items -> items.collect(List.collector()));
```

### Problem

As is, the `Map` is coming back `null`. I'm trying to get to a point where:

```
firstRowItem.getPrefixedFields() == ImmutableMap.of(
    "first thing", "a value here",
    "another.thing", "another value")

secondRowItem.getPrefixedFields() == ImmutableMap.of(
    "first thing", "values",
    "secondThing", "all",
    "another.thing", "throughout")
```

The "pf." prefix is set in stone, and everything works if the property is named "pf":

```
class Item {
    // ...
    private Map<String, String> pf;
    // ...
}
```

but I'd like for the property to be named "prefixedFields" instead of "pf".

### Attempts at resolution

- The [SimpleFlatMapper docs on property mapping](https://simpleflatmapper.org/0201-property-mapping.html) shows how to match the "pf." prefix, but doesn't cover aliasing a `Map`:

```java
.addColumnProperty(
    col -> col.getName().startsWith("pf."),
    MapTypeProperty.KEY_VALUE)
```

- `.addAlias` only accepts `String` params, so something like this doesn't work:

```
.addAlias("pf.", "prefixedFields")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A comment on a GitHub issue from the project owner](https://github.com/arnaudroger/SimpleFlatMapper/issues/555#issuecomment-425715677) got me on the right track.

`addColumnProperty` accepts varargs of `Object`. You can pass in a `RenameProperty`, which accepts either a `String` param for simple column renaming or a `Function<String, String> renameFunction`. Put those together like so:

```java
final CsvMapper<Item> mapper = CsvMapperFactory.newInstance()
    .addAlias("name", "itemName")
    .addAlias("reference #", "reference")
    .addColumnProperty(
        column -> column.getName().startsWith("pf."),
        new RenameProperty(columnName -> columnName.replace("pf.", "prefixedFields_")))
    .newMapper(Item.class);
```